# Adding index at uitableview is not working in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am loading contacts in UITableView and I want to add index at the right end for user to navigate through contacts.

I am using the code:

```
var indexOfNames = [String]()
let indexNames = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
indexOfNames = indexNames.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return indexOfNames
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
    let temp = indexOfNames as NSArray
    return temp.indexOfObject(title)
}
```

But it is not working. When I tap on the index, the table view comes to the top row. i.e. `A`. I have set the delegates for tableview. Maybe there is some issues with Swift 2.0?

Comment: What value is `temp.indexOfObject(title)` returning?  Does your table have 26 sections with rows for all of them?

Comment: `temp.indexOfObject(title)`  is index of all row data. i.e. A, B, C... and No I dont have 26 sections. But I dont know how to code that

Comment: My question was really about whether the number you're returning as an index actually matches some section that the table can reasonably go to.

Comment: No, I dont think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adding index to UITableView working for me may help you (for swift 2.0):**

```
 var arrIndexSection : NSMutableArray = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

 //MARK:- TableView Datasource/DataDelegate Method
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrIndexSection.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return arrIndexSection.objectAtIndex(section) as? String
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return self.arrIndexSection as? [String]
    }
```